# Некорректно выводятся иностранные буквы

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

создал таблицу с разными языками, у всех колонок кодировка utf8_unicode,кроме колонок с русскими буквами, там utf8_general-ci и сама таблица сравнивается по utf8_unicode,при выводе с php через encode корректно выводятся только английские буквы, a остальные (китайский, японский и русский) выводятся примерно так \u0420\u041e\u042b\u0420\u0410\u041e\u0410\u0420\u041e, как это исправить ?

P.S. Функция вывода:

```
<?php

require_once 'db_config.php'; // подключаем скрипт

// подключаемся к серверу
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) 
    or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));



if(isset($_REQUEST["wordEnglish"])){
    $wordEnglish =$_REQUEST["wordEnglish"];
$query ="SELECT * FROM translated_words WHERE wordEnglish = '$wordEnglish'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link)); 
    if($result)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)){
       $client["wordEnglish"] = $row["wordEnglish"];
        $client["defenitionEnglish"] = $row["defenitionEnglish"];
         $client["wordRussian"] = $row["wordRussian"];
          $client["defenitionRussian"] = $row["defenitionRussian"];
           $client["wordChina"] = $row["wordChina"];
            $client["defenitionChina"] = $row["defenitionChina"];
             $client["wordJapan"] = $row["wordJapan"];
              $client["defenition_Japan"] = $row["defenition_Japan"];

    }

}
}
if(isset($client)){
 echo (json_encode($client));
}
 else{
echo (json_encode(null));
}
// закрываем подключение
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: Это юникод. База данных сохраняет те данные, которые вы ей подаете. Значит вы их в таком виде и сохраняли.

Comment: @Jean-Claude подавал я ей иероглифы и русские буквы, а вывод через encode такой происходит, мне кодировку поменять стоит?

Comment: стоит пересмотреть функцию вывода. при чем тут вообще бд..

Comment: @Jean-Claude, вывод реализован через encode,php код прикрепил к теме

Comment: Это вполне нормальный json с иностранными буквами, никаких исправлений здесь не требуется

Comment: json_encode($a, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)  http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php  http://php.net/manual/ru/json.constants.php

Comment: @Jean-Claude прощу прощения что потратил ваше время, нужно было доку сначала прочесть, но вы мне правда очень помогли

Answer (score 1):

```
echo (json_encode($client,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

Ответ был дан в комментарии к вопросу.